# column names along their headings php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Helo, I want to print and retrieve column names  along their headings or their catagories title .. I'm using the following code to print the column names:

```
$arrlength=count($sort); 
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)   
{   
    echo "  <TD class=\"tr1 td26\"><P class=\"p12 ft4\">".$sort[$x]."</P></TD>";  
}
```

I want to print the column names along their column headings, how can i retrieve them if i have the following table schema:
**col heading 1 - col1

```
col heading 1 - col2
col heading 2 - col1
col heading 2 - col2
col heading 3 - col1
col heading 3 - col2
col heading 3 - col3
col heading 3 - col4


col heading 1     col heading 2     col heading 3
-------------     -------------     -------------------------   
col1    col2      col1    col2      col1   col2   col3   col4
```

I can store column headings in other table so that It can be replaced or printed in their particular place ..

Thankx in anticipation .. ;)

Comment: retreive the column headings and column names from mysql database

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the column names in php using PDO:

```
private function showColumns($table_schema, $table_name){
    $stmt = self::$_db->prepare("SELECT column_name, column_key, column_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
                                table_schema = :table_schema AND table_name = :table_name");
    $stmt->execute(array(':table_schema' => $table_schema,':table_name' => $table_name));
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: how to retreieve along column headings also .. ?

Comment: What do you mean with column heading?. If you are referring to a way of show the columns in your code, perhaps you should store this data in a table or something. Please be more clear

Comment: in table .. it store with these coloumn names .. col heading 1 - col1

col heading 1 - col2
col heading 2 - col1
col heading 2 - col2
col heading 3 - col1
col heading 3 - col2
col heading 3 - col3
col heading 3 - col4